# Can not create flow with mule esb

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

I want to create flow Mule ESB as below, but cannot create:

1. Publish CXF web service
2. Create client web service consumer.
3. Join step 1 and step 2

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried till now ? What are the issues you are facing while

1. Publish CXF web service
2. Create client web service consumer.
3. Join step 1 and step 2  ??

Anyways, you need to use Mule CXF component to create and expose a SOAP based web services and need to go through following docs https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/building-web-services-with-cxf

For consuming a Soap based web services , you need to use Mule web service consumer . Here more details :- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/web-service-consumer

You question 3 is hard to understand and you need to provide your use case here

Comment: Thanks anirban!

My use case is: 
I try create one Mule flow to emulate ESB with many clients and many servers exchange data, Mule ESB is center.

I'm a newbie, :). I read mule tutorial, but can not create this use case.

Comment: you need to create different flows to consume different service. You can use web service consumer to consume the data

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way:

[image]

You need to:

1. Define Http Connector with an endpoint on which Listener can receive
   requests
2. Define a Java Interface to set in CXF block Properties
   which will be the definition of your exposed WSDL
3. Set in VM client block the queue name referring VM server block Set in WS Consumer the WSDL link that you want to call and specify, in the same block, the service and the operation that you want to call
4. Flag in WS
       Consumer block DataSense option to inherit automatically in the
       Datamapper (or Dataweave if you prefer) blocks the I/O structures
       for request/response of WS

Remember that, after a CXF block, you will have a Java object in your payload, whereas WS Consumer use XML structures for request and response: for this reason your input Datamapper (or Dataweave) will transform Pojo to XML and your output Datamapper (or Dataweave) will transform XML to Pojo.
I hope this can help you